# Erroneous output in printing prime numbers

Tags: javascript

The code incorrectly computes many non-prime numbers as prime, and I am not sure why. Basically the output alternates "prime" and "not prime" for the input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

for (var i = 3; i <= 30; i++) {
  console.log(i + ": " + isPrime(i) + " ");
}

function isPrime(num) {
  var counter;

  for (counter = 2; counter < num; counter++) {
    if(num % counter == 0) {
      return "not prime";
    }
    else {
      return "prime";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably because all it's doing is determine odd/even. You probably don't want to return immediately in the for loop, but instead do it after, based on a condition (that it isn't divisible by any of the numbers below it)

Comment: Got to love the rampant, drive-by downvotes on answers with no comments... Anyway, the `return "prime"` needs to be outside of your `for` loop.

Comment: And if you want it more efficent, you only have to check divisors up to and including the greatest integer of the `sqrt(num)`, not all the way up to `num`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return true after the loop, not inside the loop. for instance, the number is 9. first iteration if(9%2 == 0)-false else return prime. but nine is not prime. only return true after you are through iterating and you'll find the expected result.

```
function isPrime(num) {
var counter;

for (counter = 2; counter < num; counter++) {
if(num % counter == 0) {
  return " not prime";
}
}
  return " prime";
}
```

Comment: His calling function expects a string.

Answer (score 0):

num % 2 is num mod 2, which just means the remainder of the number after being divided by two.

What you would really like to do is something like this:

```
primes = [2]
for (var i=0;i<primes.length;i++){
    if (primes[i]<sqrt(num)){
        if (num % primes[i] == 0){
            console.log("Not prime!");}
        }
    else{
        console.log("prime!");
        primes.push(num);
    }
}
```

When you're determining primes, you should only be trying to construct the prime factorization of the number you're checking, otherwise you're doing FAR more work than you should be doing. Since the prime factorization is by definition constructed of primes, those are the only numbers you should check for modularity.

Additionally you should only check up to the square root of the number because any number that it is divisible by will have a matching number. Examples:

```
104 = 57*2
39 = 13*3
```

Complexity goes from O(n) to O(log(sqrt(n)) which is 4 comparisons instead of 100 even at an n of just 100 and it just keeps getting better.

Comment: Why on earth is this downvoted? This is exactly how you should check for primes, check all primes up to the sqrt of the number being checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 3; i <= 30; i++) {
  console.log(i + ": " + isPrime(i) + " ");
}

function isPrime(num) {
  var counter;

  for (counter = 2; counter < num; counter++) {
    if(num % counter == 0) {
      return "not prime";
    }
  }
  // only return that it is prime if it is not evenly
  // divisible by all numbers less than it
  // (technically you only need to check up to sqrt(num) + 1)
  return "prime";
}
```

Comment: Not sqrt(num) +1, just floor(sqrt(num))

Comment: Yeah, my wording was not exact, when I said check up to I meant use (counter < sqrt(num) + 1) as the terminating condition in the for loop.  If using floor, the condition should change to (counter <= sqrt(num)) otherwise 4, 9, 16, ... would be incorrectly detected as prime.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WJEfv/)

You have to return prime after the loop is done with check

```
for (var i = 3; i <= 30; i++) {
  console.log(i + ": " + isPrime(i) + " ");
}

function isPrime(num) {
  var counter;

  for (counter = 2; counter < num; counter++) {
    if(num % counter == 0) {
     return "not prime";
    }
  }
  return "prime";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

the first time something misses your `f(num % counter == 0)` condition, it will return as not prime

the easiest thing to take your `return "prime";` call out of your for-loop

```
function isPrime(num) {
    for(counter = 2; counter < num; counter++) {

        if(num % counter == 0) {
            return "not prime";
        }
    }
    return "prime";
}
```